# Firebase.set failed: second argument must be a valid function

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Following Lynda.com Building a data-driven app with angular and Firebase.
I am getting the above message when I attempt to use the register function with set(). set() is still in the angularfire API. I have tried searching SO and the docs but cannot find the answer.

authentication.js

```
myApp.factory('Authentication', function($firebase, 
  $firebaseAuth, $routeParams, $location, FIREBASE_URL) {

  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
  var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

  //Temporary object
  var myObject = {

    login: function(user) {
      return auth.$authWithPassword({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }); //authWithPassword
    }, //login

    register: function(user) {
      return auth.$createUser({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }).then(function(regUser) {
        var firebaseUsers = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+'users');

        var userInfo = {
          date : Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
          regUser : regUser.uid,
          firstname: user.firstname,
          lastname : user.lastname,
          email: user.email
        }; //user info

        firebaseUsers.set(regUser.uid, userInfo); //**ERRORS HERE**
      }); //promise
    } //register

  }; //myObject
  return myObject;
}); //myApp Factory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's set method is documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html. It is pretty explicit:

> onComplete Function *optional
>
> A callback function that will be called when synchronization to the Firebase servers has completed. The callback will be passed an Error object on failure; else null.

So the second (optional) argument is a function that will be called when the value has been set on the server. If you copied that exact code from the tutorial, you should probably reach out to the author and ask them what they were meaning to do.

What they more likely wanted to do, was set the user data in a child node. To do that replace the problematic line with this:

```
firebaseUsers.child(regUser.uid).set(userInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I now see a comment on the course homepage that says since the course was released a couple of weeks ago, Firebase has updated their API. It suggests using an older version of the API. I am keen to learn the new API but am finding these stumbling blocks.

Comment: Does `set` merge values?